# The Dolibarr API changes the values sent in Python

Tags: python, dolibarr

I have an application that creates orders in Dolibarr. It works but some fields seems to be set automatically (with wrong values) although the correct values are sent.
I use the [docs](https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php?title=Module_Web_Services_API_REST_(developer)#Examples_with_Python) to create my calls. It's a product that is created in the example but I am using the same structure to create my orders. The totals are false: total_ht, total_tva, total_ttc. I am sure that the values I sent are correct and I checked the names of the fields both with insomnia and directly in the database (and in the swagger explorer provided).

I can set fields such as "ref" and "note_private" without any issue but some other fields don't take my values into account. I have the exact same issue with some order lines. I have two fields "tva_tx" and "vat_src_code" that are not always set as I want.

I checked and the values that are sent are very consistant so I should have the same result every time. Unless I am missing something...

This is what I send. I only show a few fields to avoid extra long code.

```
        order = {
            'ref': prestashop_item.get('reference'),
            'note_private': note_private,
            'type': 0,
            'lines': order_lines,
            'total_tva': float(tempTotalTaxes),
            'total_ht': float(prestashop_item.get('total_paid_tax_excl', 0)),
            'total_ttc': float(prestashop_item.get('total_paid_tax_incl', 0)),
        }
```

And my call is `ret_val = dolibarr_inst.call_create_api('orders', order)`, same as in the doc.